# chart.js - how to draw a thicker horizontal line at the zero point of a graph with negative and positive values

Tags: javascript, chart.js, visualization

I'm building a stacked bar chart in [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html) and trying to make the zero point line (the point at which forest loss is at zero for each decade) darker / more obvious than the other horizontal grid lines. Is there an option for this? If not, how might I accomplish it with code?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mentioned at the [Styling](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html) section in the docs and it's called lineWidth.

This related question might also be helpful: [Chart.js how to use scriptable options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63977011/chart-js-how-to-use-scriptable-options)

```
options {
  scales: {
    y: {
      grid: {
        lineWidth: ({ tick }) => tick.value == 0 ? 10 : 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```